# How can I click "onclick" elements using selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, onclick

I have been trying to click an element that has an onclick event to download a file.

HTML code.

[image]

Interface.

[Form interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M45wn.png)

I have tried the following ways to click on purpose to download the file but it shows the following errors.

`driver.find_element(By.ID, "frmForma1:btnConsultar").click()`

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: ...
```

`WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body[1]/div[2]/form/fieldset/div/div/input'))).click()`

```
It shows the same error as above
```

`WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "frmForma1:btnConsultar[onclick*='clearFormHiddenParams_frmForma1']"))).click()`

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element
```

`WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[onclick*='clearFormHiddenParams_frmForma1('frmForma1')']"))).click()`

```
InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression
```

page.html

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hebermudezg/aa85601d6b0ef2ad0758e7d9da1edce3/raw/263ed3449e9d3fd67bf3bbbe0a4c3d040f6ce022/page.html

Comment: Can you post the URL?

Comment: Please share a link to that page or at least all that page XML/HTML as a text.

Comment: you can add a time.sleep(5) before clicking it to wait for complete load of page

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add sleep function after you load url

```
time.sleep(3)
```